# Xcode Project signing with Id not available after adding account to Xcode

Tags: xcode

Team name and its role not showing anything after adding account in Xcode-->Preferences-->Account

[image]

Comment: Is everything set up correctly in ADC? Why are the Download Manual Profiles and Manage Certificates buttons disabled?

Comment: Everything was working perfect before xcode 9.2 update. i dont know why these buttons are disabled

Comment: I updated to 9.2 beta last weekend and while I haven't made any changes in ADC my buttons are enabled. I'm using build 9C34b.

Comment: When i add other apple account then everything works fine, but this issue arises when i add account which is enrolled in apple developer program

Comment: ok problem is solved. Actually i requested the Apple to transfer Developer Program License Agreement to an organization, so they disablde my memebership benefits temporarily

Comment: That might be worth putting an answer to your question. Others may have the same thing happen.